# Login Page return Request-URI Too Long, Dreamweaver $MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php" Error

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I am trying to setup a login page with different user level. I am working from this SimpleTut Tutorial on How to build a User Registration System - Registration, Login, Email Password, Update, Admin Backend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qqcj4nYkcks.

I notice that the code written with Databases, Binding and Server Behaviour gives alot of problem especially with mysqli.

```
        <?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {

    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")

    {
    /*Global variable $con is necessary, because it is not known inside the function and you need it for mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $theValue); the Variable $con ist defined as mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password", "database") with an include-script.
    */

      Global $connection;
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }
      $theValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    //mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
      $errorr = "You have an issue with the connection.";
      $connection = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "yardiemovie");
    $query_Login = "SELECT * FROM yardiecustomers";
    /* $Login = mysql_query($connection, $query_Login) or die(mysql_error($connection));
    $row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login);
    $totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login) */
    ?>
    <?php
    // *** Validate request to login to this site.
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
    }

    $loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
      $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
      $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];
      $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "UserLevel";
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "account.php";
      $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php";
      $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
      $connection = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "yardiemovie");

      $LoginRS__query="";
      $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM yardiecustomers WHERE username=%s AND Password=%s",
      GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

      $error = "You have an issue with the connection."; 
      $LoginRS = mysqli_query($connection, $LoginRS__query) or die(mysql_error(error));
      $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
      if ($loginFoundUser) {

        $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'UserLevel');


        if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
        //declare two session variables and assign them
        $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
        $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

        if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
          $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
        }
        header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
      }
      else {
        header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
      }
    }

    $MM_authorizedUsers = "1";
    $MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

    // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
    function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
      // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
      $isValid = False; 

      // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
      // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
      if (!empty($UserName)) { 
        // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
        // Parse the strings into arrays. 
        $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
        $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
        if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
        if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
      } 
      return $isValid; 
    }

        $MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
            if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])&& true) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
          $MM_qsChar = "?";
          $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
          if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
          if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
          $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
          $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
          header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
          exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Can someone say whats happening?
This is normally the result.
http://localhost:8080/MovieRentalSite/login.php?accesscheck=%2FMovieRentalSite%2Flogin.php%3Faccesscheck%3D%252FMovieRentalSite%252Flogin.php%253Faccesscheck%253D%25252FMovieRentalSite%25252Flogin.php%25253Faccesscheck%25253D%2525252FMovieRentalSite%2525252Flogin.php%2525253Faccesscheck%2525253D%252525252FMovieRentalSite%252525252Flogin.php%2......525252525252525252525252525252525252Flogin.php

Thanks

Comment: First off, "A lot of problems" doesn't really help to troubleshoot the issue. When you ask a question you should post the error you get and the result you expect.
Second, the link you posted points to your own computer and cannot be accessed from anybody else but you (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Comment: Thanks Tony, I am running the server locally. Error: multiple redirect. Expectations: redirect if user authenticate and stay on login page if user don't.

Comment: What page is the one you posted? login.php?

Comment: can you copy and paste the error you get?

Comment: I am not getting a php error "The page isn't redirecting properly" please see the file https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArTNSeyQje2VlkcNCLU9amljLdgO

Comment: First of all on lines 72 and 73 you are using `mysql_num_rows` with `mysqli` results, same on line 76... you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`...

Comment: you are not getting any php error because before it can actually output the errors you get redirected to the same page, in an infinite loop... To troubleshoot, comment out the `header` functions and put something like `echo __LINE__;` and see which line # comes out so you can identify where the script is going wrong...